# Where are tokens stored from an implementation level

Tags: tokens

I have the following questions:

1.From a LevelDB perspective, where are tokens stored? Is it part of account info? Or is it only part of the smart contract?

2. If it is only part of the contract, how does block explorer know what tokens each account has?
3. Anyone can point me to the relevant implementation files in aleth impl?

Answer (score 3):

> 1. From a LevelDB perspective, where are tokens stored? Is it part of account info? Or is it only part of the smart contract?

LevelDB is key/value storage then the key will depends on the smart contract address and the address of the token holder in the balance mapping. We can say that token balance is part of smart contract's state and the account is only the key in the smart contract balance mapping.

For detail you can refer to this link

https://medium.com/aigang-network/how-to-read-ethereum-contract-storage-44252c8af925

> 2. If it is only part of the contract, how does block explorer know what
>      tokens each account has?

Blockexplorer will watch events or reading tnx's receipt/logs of relevant token smart contract's transactions to record the token balance of each account/address.

> 3. Anyone can point me to the relevant implementation files in aleth
>      impl?

This is the implement code to read the data by specific key

```
// GetState returns a value in account storage.
func (self *stateObject) GetState(db Database, key common.Hash) common.Hash {
    value, exists := self.cachedStorage[key]
    if exists {
        return value
    }
    // Load from DB in case it is missing.
    enc, err := self.getTrie(db).TryGet(key[:])
    if err != nil {
        self.setError(err)
        return common.Hash{}
    }
    if len(enc) > 0 {
        _, content, _, err := rlp.Split(enc)
        if err != nil {
            self.setError(err)
        }
        value.SetBytes(content)
    }
    self.cachedStorage[key] = value
    return value
}
```

Comment: i dont think you are answering my question at all

Comment: okay, I updated my answer base on my understanding, PTAL!

Comment: great! Would you be interested in working on a start up blockchian project? we pay competitively. give me your email!

Comment: Cool, drop me an email on dvietha@gmail.com; thanks in advance.

Comment: @user2584960 I am also interested in working on your blockchain project, put your email on your profile and I will contact you.

Comment: @Nulik I apologize, I cannot disclose my email. Can you give me mine? Much appreciated.

Comment: @user2584960, where here nuliknol@gmail.com

Comment: i emailed you both

Comment: @user2584960, I have replied you back, but from another email address, check your spam folder if it doesn't arrive